HTML-like labels in chl parameter of image-charts url?
Is it possible to use HTML-like labels (with angle brackets) in the chl parameter of an image-charts graphviz URL? I'm calling the URL from an iOS app to create an AsyncImage.
I am trying to use some the Musical Flat Sign, Musical Sharp Sign and Degree Sign HTML entities, as image-charts doesn't seem to render those correctly in raw string or unicode format. The Graphviz Visual Editor seems capable of displaying those characters, but I think there's a lot of parsing going on under the hood which I don't really understand. I just want to use a String for the chl parameter and then assign that to a URLQueryItem.
The problem I'm encountering is anytime I try to use angle brackets for a label (like Cma13 [label=<C major 13>] in my chl parameter, I get the following error:
ERROR In 'chl' parameter, Cannot read properties of null (reading '3')
Or if I just use angle brackets for the node name directly (like <Cma13> -> Cma9, I get the following:
In 'chl' parameter, Expected "edge", "graph", "node", "subgraph","{","}", comment, identifier or whitespace but "<" found.
So is there a way to format/escape the angle brackets in the chl string in order to use HTML-like labels, or is that just not possible?
Thanks for looking.
Jake

According to the docs:

Only URL-safe characters are permitted in label strings. To be safe, you should URL-encode any strings containing characters not in the character set 0-9a-zA-Z.

Let's try encoding the Degree Sign in different ways:



Encoded sign
Result on image




°
deg


%C2%B0 (URL-safe)
%C2%B0


&deg;
deg


&#176;
deg


&#xB0;
deg



Changing the charset doesn't help.
However, &#169; or &copy; return ©!
It looks like a problem on the service side, maybe hardcore sanitizing, maybe a bug.
Try to email the developers or open an issue in the project repo on GitHub.
So, the HTML tag is not rendered, but you can get an <C major 13> caption using entity names: label="&lt;C major 13&gt".

Thanks, I'll email them!
